# Get the page height taking into account @page styles and as if the page would be set to 800px wide

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, window

I'm trying to use `window.print()` to save my webpage as a PDF. I want it to be a continuous one file (so not divided into a few A4 pages, etc.). I don't think there is a CSS solution to do this, so I've decided to use JS/jQuery.

```
<div class="pdf-btn-inner">
    <p>Save</p>
</div>
```

```
@media print {

    @page{ 
        margin:0;
        size:800px 100%; /* It will be overwritten by JS */
    }

    /* The code changing the look of the page when using window.print() below... */
}
```

```
$(".pdf-btn-inner").on("click", function(){
    window.print();
});

$(window).on('load', function(){
    let pageHeight = $(document).height();

    var cssPagedMedia = (function () {
        var style = document.createElement('style');
        document.head.appendChild(style);
        return function (rule) {
            style.innerHTML = rule;
        };
    }());

    cssPagedMedia.size = function (size) {
        cssPagedMedia('@page {size: ' + size + '}');
    };

    cssPagedMedia.size('800px ' + pageHeight + 'px');
});
```

The script above changes the `@page size` to be 800px wide and the height is set to be the same as the webpage on load. There are 2 problems. **The first one** - it doesn't take into account that the page looks different (different styles when printing). There is no footer, nav, some divs look different, etc. **The second problem** - it sets the height based on the user's screen (so usually 1920px width). The page has a different height when the width changes - rows turn into columns, etc.
Is there a way to take into account the `@page` styles and virtually set the page width to 800px to get the webpage height? I don't want to literally set it to 800px, it should do it behind the scenes. Is that possible?